# How to translate "tu as toute ta place ici" from French

Tags: translation, french

I am actually writing my first song in English and was wondering how to translate **"tu as toute ta place ici"** from French to English. It means *"this is your place, yours, truly yours, you can stay"*.

My attempt: You've got a whole place here?

Comment: What about: "you belong here".

Comment: Oddly enough, in English, I feel like we use the Spanish loan-phrase "Mi casa es tu casa" more than we use any natively English phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the word *whole* fits very well with what you're trying to say. What's worse, the word *hole* (a homophone of *whole*) often refers to a run-down establishment, so your meaning might be further lost in song.

Here's one way you could translate the phrase into vernacular English:

> *You have a home away from home here*

The phrase "home away from home" is a rather common idiom; it means a place where you can feel as comfortable as you do at home (see listing at [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/home%20away%20from%20home)).

Another way you could say something close might be:

> *You are always welcome here*